# Prove by cases that for all positive integers $n^n > n^{n-1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, integers

> Prove by cases that for all positive integers $n^n > n^{n-1}$

How am I going to make cases for this proposition? There are an infinite number of positive integers.

Comment: $n^n > n^n - 1$ or $n^n > n^{n-1}$ ? I have a feeling which one you are talking about

Comment: Note that strictly inequality fails for $n=1$, a positive integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$n^n > n^{n-1} = \frac{n^n}{n} \tag{*}$$

Well we know $n \ne 0$ so $(*)$ is equivalent to

$$1 > \frac{1}{n} \tag{**}$$

$(**)$ is true for $n > 1$

Therefore $(*)$ is true if $n > 1$

Both $(**)$ and $(*)$ do not hold for $n=1$